# Extracting Values from certain time limit in Simulated Data using R

Tags: r

I tried to do a stochastic simulation on a epidemiology SEIR model using the coding below.

```
library(GillespieSSA)
parms <- c(beta=0.591,sigma=1/8,gamma=1/7)
x0 <- c(S=50,E=0,I=1,R=0)
a <- c("beta*S*I","sigma*E","gamma*I") 
nu <- matrix(c(-1,0,0,
            1,-1,0,
            0,1,-1,
            0,0,1),nrow=4,byrow=TRUE)

set.seed(12345)
out <- lapply(X=1:10,FUN=function(x) ssa(x0,a,nu,parms,tf=50)$data)
out
```

I managed to obtain the 10 simulations values that I wanted. The time is in continuous form. Now, I have to extract time in discrete form such as 1,2,3...,50 from each simulation. Which type of coding should I use?

I tried doing data.frame and extract but still not able to do it.

Thanking in advance for any help.

Comment: The simulated data with time values 0.02,0.003 and so on should be deleted from the data. Only time values such as 0.00,0.98.1.9 which is near to 0,1,2 should be extracted.

Comment: you want to down-sample? can you post a reproducible example? showing how you want to go from vector A to vector B.

Comment: @e4e5f4. Hello. Thank you for your reply. Let's say I add these coding to the above coding :a<-as.data.frame(out)
write.csv(out, file="out1.csv")
out1 <- read.csv("out1.csv",header=T)
out1[1,]

From here I can get the data for time 0.0000. It's easy because for the simulations, all the values for time 0 is in row 1. But for time 1,2 and so on, it differs. So, I have no idea how to extract those values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say the data looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(t=seq(0.4,4.5,0.03), x=1:137)

##       t   x
## 1   0.40   1
## 2   0.43   2
## 3   0.46   3
## 4   0.49   4
## 5   0.52   5
```

To get the discrete time index values:

```
idx <- diff(ceiling(df$t)) == 1
```

Discrete time series will be:

```
df[idx,]

##        t   x
## 21  1.00  21
## 54  1.99  54
## 87  2.98  87
## 121 4.00 121
```

Comment: Yes, this is the one I'm asking for! Thank you. But, may I know how this coding works? "idx <- diff(ceiling(df$t)) == 1"

Comment: it is easy to start reading from inside out. `ceiling` will create a sequence like `1,1,...,2,2,...,3,3,...`. Taking `diff` will give `1`s at places where the value changes. Checking `==1` will result in logical vector with `TRUE` at those points and `FALSE` elsewhere.

Comment: I've tried to do that in my coding. I did get the output, but after it takes value from 16,.. then it straight gives the value for 23 onwards. How can I alter that in my coding in order to get each time interval? The coding is like below :

library(GillespieSSA)

parms <- c(beta=0.591,sigma=1/8,gamma=1/7)

x0 <- c(S=50,E=0,I=1,R=0)

a <- c("beta*S*I","sigma*E","gamma*I") 

nu <- matrix(c(-1,0,0,
1,-1,0,
0,1,-1,
0,0,1),nrow=4,byrow=TRUE)
set.seed(12345)
out <- lapply(X=1:1,FUN=function(x) ssa(x0,a,nu,parms,tf=50)$data)
out
a<-as.data.frame(out)
idx <- diff(ceiling(a$V1)) == 1
a[idx,]

Comment: in your data some values are missing (not really continuous!). try: `idx <- diff(ceiling(a$V1)) != 0`

Comment: Yes some are missing. Since its a stochastic simulation, I don't know how to get a output with each interval from 0-1,1-2 until 50. But, anyway, this does helps a lot.

One more question, since there is no value for interval 20-21 and more, is there any coding such that I can add the value inside myself? Because, if there is no reading for that time interval, that means the readings are same until the next interval.

Comment: yes, its possible. Probably a separate question, but you can simply create a data frame with time index (column 1) going from `1` to `last time step` and values (column 2) = `0`. Then fill the corresponding values from `a[idx,]` to this new data frame.

Comment: comments are getting too long, with difficulty in formatting. Come up with a simple reproducible example and post it as a separate question.

Comment: I don't really get you. I'm sorry. I'm new to R. I will post this as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Having run the trial myself a problem seems to be that many of the time stamps are quite a distance from an integer result.

To see these remainders, check: `out[[1]][,1] %% 1`

The good news is that you can use the output from this, with a tuning parameter, to select what you want. For this purpose, you'll want to find the distance from one and then control for what's an acceptable gap.

Do this as follows and save the result (and bunch of `TRUE` and `FALSE` results)

```
selection <- abs((out[[1]][,1] %% 1) - 1) < 0.1
```

You can then subset the matrix `out` using the `selection` index we just saved:

```
out[[1]][selection,]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for a prompt reply. I appreciate it a lot.

When I run the coding you stated, I did get the output, but for I have four readings for 0.9 values of time. I just need one in that interval. As in one reading for 0.0, one reading for 0.9, one for 1.9 as all these numbers are near to 0,1,2 and so on. 

I'm sorry, perhaps I didn't make myself clear.

Comment: so what you need is the single value that's closest to each integer?